# '#' character in URL

Tags: javascript, http, url

Following is my URL that has '#' character in it,problem is after '#' all data it`s skipping,i checked the going URL in fiddler(Software).

> `http://someIPAddress/folder.asp?ID=1&ID1=2&ID2=3&name=name name1 # 1&skip=0`

Can someone tell me why this is happening?What`s wrong using '#' in URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` specifies the hash/anchor portion of the URL. It looks like you're putting data in your URL without escaping it to encode special characters like `#` or `%` into `%23` or `%25`. Encode it using `encodeURIComponent`.

So something like this:

```
'http://someIPAddress/folder.asp?ID=1&ID1=2&ID2=3&name=' + someVar + '&skip=0'
```

should become:

```
'http://someIPAddress/folder.asp?ID=1&ID1=2&ID2=3&name=' + encodeURIComponent(someVar) + '&skip=0'
```

Comment: I didnt get what hash/anchor mean here?could you please explain a little bit?Why should it escape info?

Comment: @user1495475: Anchors specify a position on the page based on `id` (or `name` on an `<a>` tag) to jump to. Just like `?` and `&`, they have a special meaning in URLs, so you need to escape them.